# Write/read PNG metadata: nothing saved/nothing read

Tags: .net, f#

I have 2 functions: to write and read meta-data into/from PNG file. This is the adaption of MSDN example for C#. No errors, but nothing is written (check it with tweakpng tool too). I found that for JPG padding is needed, but no such info for PNG. What is wrong with this code? (I tried other `MetaKey` values, also with "/Text/..." prefix, no success. Also I tried to read existing "key" (added with tweakpng tool) - nothing (null). I saw on one of MSDN examples one comment that this code does not work, but no other examples there... The code:

```
    open System.IO
    open System.Text
    open System.Security.Cryptography
    open System.Windows.Media.Imaging


    let MetaKey = "/tEXt/Description"
    let WriteMeta (path : string, a : int, from : b) =
        let data = sprintf "%d %d" a b
        use stm = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        let dec = new PngBitmapDecoder (stm, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default)
        let frm = dec.Frames.[0]
        let wr = frm.CreateInPlaceBitmapMetadataWriter ()
        let mutable res = false
        if wr.TrySave () then
            wr.SetQuery (MetaKey, data.ToCharArray())
            res <- true
        stm.Close ()
        res

    let ReadMeta (path : string) =
        use stm = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        let dec = new PngBitmapDecoder (stm, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default)
        let met = dec.Frames.[0].Metadata :?> BitmapMetadata
        let data = met.GetQuery (MetaKey)
        let res =
            match data with
            | null -> None
            | obj -> Some <| obj.ToString ()
        stm.Close ()
        res
```

Comment: It's hard to help when in the question the code is not runnable, ie doens't include all dependencies, all ``open`` statements or specifiy (by ``#r``) all dlls that are required to run it.

Answer (score 1):

As I found, it's a good known problem, due to MSDN documentation: it shows only keeping of metadata but not saving back to file. This code works:

```
    let MetaKey = "/tEXt/Description"
    let WriteMeta (path : string, data : string) =
        let fip = new FileInfo (path)
        use stm = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        let dec = new PngBitmapDecoder (stm, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad)
        let frm = dec.Frames.[0]
        let _met = frm.Metadata
        if _met = null then
            stm.Close ()
            false
        else
            let met = _met.Clone () :?> BitmapMetadata
            stm.Close ()
            fip.Delete ()
            met.SetQuery (MetaKey, data)
            let enc = new PngBitmapEncoder ()
            enc.Frames.Add (BitmapFrame.Create (frm, frm.Thumbnail, met, frm.ColorContexts))
            use stm' = File.Open (path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            enc.Save (stm')
            stm'.Close ()
            true

    let ReadMeta (path : string) =
        use stm = new FileStream (path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)
        let dec = new PngBitmapDecoder (stm, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default)
        let met = dec.Frames.[0].Metadata :?> BitmapMetadata
        if met = null then None
        else
            let data = met.GetQuery (MetaKey)
            let res =
                match data with
                | null -> None
                | obj -> Some <| obj.ToString ()
            stm.Close ()
            res
```